# Javascript: Structure declaration differences

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hopefully this is simple.  What is different between this:

```
data = {
    scheduleDates: dates.join(","),
    locationid: locationid,
    instructorid: 157
};
```

and

```
var data = {};
data.scheduleDates = dates.join(",");
data.locationid = locationid;
data.instructorid = 157;
```

Reason I ask is I spent the last half hour battling with an issue where my data wasn't being sent to the server using $.ajax.  I have used the second version many times in this app and it worked just fine.  I used the first example in one other place, so I tried it, and it worked.

So... what exactly is different about those two ways of declaring that structure??

Thanks.

Comment: Those two pieces of code will have exactly the same effect assuming you fix the fact that the first one is missing `var`

Comment: That particular struct was var'd previously in the code, fwiw. :)

Comment: There isn't much difference I think. I'd consider the first one more readable, but the second one is useful if you need to instantiate properties based on other properties.

Comment: OK, I suspected so. In that case it wasn't this that was preventing your ajax operation from working.